# Run Function If user delete the word

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a jQuery code for sending keywords to another page.On that page I have names of all countries. my code works good also, I have defined my function in a condition that if the lenght of text of input was longer than 2 then runs the function inside it but, I have problem with this for Example when I write the city name it works good and returns the correct data from the ajax page my issue is when the user wants to delete that word with backspace or somthing else I want to remove all previous data was sent to ajax page but because of my condition it does not work.

how can I define if user delete the word run my function ?

here is my code :

```js
var prevXHR = null; //global
$('.country').each(function() {
  $(this).on('keyup', function(e) {
  var _this = this;
  var element = $(this).val().length;
  if (e.which !== 0 &&
     !e.ctrlKey && !e.metaKey && !e.altKey
    ){
  if (element > 2) {
   var val = $(this).val()
   $(this).val(val)
   
       prevXHR = $.ajax({
                 url: "ajaxpage.htm",
                 type: "get",
                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                 data: {
                     key: $(this).val()
                 },
                 success: function(result) {

                 $(_this).closest(".search_div").find(".co").empty().html(result)

                 },
                 beforeSend: function(){
                     if(prevXHR && prevXHR.readyState != 20){
                         //before sending any new request neutralize any pending ajax call
                         prevXHR.abort();
                         prevXHR = null;
                     }
                 }

              });

   
  }
  
 }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search_div"> 
<input type="text" value=""  class="country" autocomplete="off" />
<div class="result"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't just use the `else` statement after you compare the length of the input? Use `else` to clear anything you don't want if the text is less than 2 characters long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are already checking to see if the length of the input was greater than 2, then proceeding with `ajax` call.

Just add `else` part afterwards.

```
if (element > 2) {
    // ...do the ajax stuff here
} else {
   // the input length was shorter than 2 characters...

   // remove all HTML elements here

   $('div#to_be_removed').remove();   //or something like that

}
```